# Invalid permissions with location services

Tags: authentication, service, permissions, location, here-api

I am using your service through the IWD store locator. My credentials are entered in to the system and the map is not showing. Support from IWD said to give you this error and see if we can fix it.

H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(8)(<ns2:Error xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Errors/1" type="PermissionError" subtype="InvalidCredentials">invalid credentials for fFHA1J6L0plavYxkzTLa</ns2:Error>)

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message are your credentials not valid to access the Here API.
How the integration of the Here API and Services is done within the IWD store locator can only the Support from IWD explain. Please reach out to them.